# LINQ select next record with each matching result

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have objects from which measurements are saved to a single table. I want to find out how long an object has been in a certain state within a time period.

So in addition to getting the record with the wanted state I need to pair it up with the next measurement made from the same object to calculate the time between them.

I came up with this monster:

```
// Get the the object entry from Database
MeasuredObject object1;
try
{
   object1 = (MeasuredObject)(from getObject in db.MeasuredObject where wantedObject.Id.Equals(getObject.Id) select getObject).Single();
}
catch (System.ArgumentNullException e)
{
   throw new System.ArgumentException("Object does not exist", "wantedObject", e);
}

// Get every measurement which matches the state in the time period and the next measurement from it
var pairs = (from m in object1.Measurements
             join nextM in object1.Measurements
             on (from next in object1.Measurements where (m.Id < next.Id) select next.Id).Min() equals nextM.Id
             where 'm is in time period and has required state'
             select new { meas = m, next = nextM });
```

I would say this doesn't seem very efficient especially when I'm using Compact Edition 3.5.

Is there any way to navigate to the next measurement through m or could I somehow use orderby or group to select next by Id? Or even make the join clause simpler?

Comment: Just for clarity, this is not LINQ to Objects, nor LINQ to Entities, but LINQ to SQL? And `Measurements` is some sort of a `IQueryable` and the whole LINQ query is executed as SQL query inside a SqlServer database?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused of the different uses around LINQ... The object1 has been taken from the database. I will add the call of the object1 in the question. The Measurements however is an SQL table which has foreign key to the object1 in database. So yes I think this is LINQ to SQL

Comment: Yeah, I know it's confusing, but that's the reality. And different sources require different solutions. The most important thing here is the **type** of the `object1.Measurements` property - please provide it, e.g. `IEnumerable<Measurement>`. `IQueryeble<Measurement>` etc.

Comment: Since I cast it to MeasuredObject I take that it becomes an entity and isn't in the database anymore. According to the DataContext MeasuredObject.Measurements is an entityset<Measurement>. would it help if I changed object1 to be IQueryable<MeasuredObject>?

Comment: No - just the solution will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the posted code looks like you are working with in memory collection. If that's true, then the following should be sufficient:

```
var items = (from m in object1.Measurements
             where 'm is in time period and has required state'
             orderby m.Id
             select m)
            .ToList();

var pairs = items.Select((item, index) => new
            {
                meas = item,
                next = index + 1 < items.Count ? items[index + 1] : null
            });
```

**EDIT:** The above is not the exact equivalent of your code because it applies the filter before pairing the items. The exact optimized equivalent would be like this:

```
var items = object1.Measurements.OrderBy(m => m.Id).ToList();

var pairs = items.Select((item, index) => new
            {
                meas = item,
                next = index + 1 < items.Count ? items[index + 1] : null
            })
            .Where(pair => 'pair.meas is in time period and has required state');
```

Comment: What does the data[] here refer to?

Comment: Sorry, it's `items`. This is what happens when you rename the variable outside the VS :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the query filters out all the other measurements. So the time in the state could not be calculated. However this gave me a new idea: get all the measurements in the period and loop through them with an index since they already are in the memory. I'll come back to say how that turned out.

Comment: This looks perfect! Thank you for your time :) I'm still a bit lost on where the index comes from but I'll try to look that up in documentation.

Comment: It comes from this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) and can only be used with LINQ method syntax.